# Обращение к xml файлу

Tags: xml, xmlparser, javascript

Я где то видел функцию, которая: загружает xml по указанному url и возвращает его.
Ещё я знаю, что выполнив:

```
var file = имяФункции('a.ru/a.xml');
```

Я смогу обращаться к file средствами DOM.

*Все бы хорошо, вот только я забыл её название и  в интернете про неё ничего не нашёл. Так что просьба, чтоб кто-нибудь **напомнил мне её название** и желательно кинул линк на статью про неё*

---

p.s. Надеюсь я её видел в реальности, и она мне не приснилась :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По соображениям безопасности в js невозможно напрямую загрузить файл, поэтому загружаем через `ajax`

```
function CreateAjax(){
    var AjaxObj;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        AjaxObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        var MSVersions = new Array( 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0',
                                    'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.5.0',
                                    'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.4.0',
                                    'MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0',
                                    'MSXML2.XMLHTTP',
                                    'Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        for (var i=0;i<MSVersions.length && !AjaxObj;i++)
        {
            try
            {
                AjaxObj = new ActiveXObject(MSVersions[i]);
            }
            catch(e){}
        }
    }
    if (!AjaxObj){alert("Ошибка создания объекта XMLHttpRequest.");}
    else {return AjaxObj;}
}

var xmlload = CreateAjax();
xmlload.open("GET","data.xml",false);
xmlload.send(null);
xmldoc= xmlload.responseXML;
```

p.s.: Всё это можно сократить до пару строчек если пользуетесь js библиотеками.

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_file()` Вроде так.

Comment: Это для php функция. У **скрипта** такой функции c таким именем нет.

Comment: извините. Проглядел:) Ну можно на ajax  с помощью этой функции реализовать. Только мучаться много надо будет.